# how to change SCSS variable based on the env | laravel 8

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-8, laravel-mix

#### I want to change the SCSS variable `$fa_font_path` based on the env `APP_DIR` ?

I have this website where on localhost/demo server It's on the subfolder and on the live server it's on the main folder, I added `APP_DIR` on .env to present the subfolder `APP_DIR=/subfoulder/` where on the live server it's `APP_DIR=/`.

I found this answer and it's not working

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
    
var fa_font_path =
    process.env.APP_DIR + "fonts/fontawesome-free/webfonts";
    mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css", {
        data: "$fa-font-path:'" + fa_font_path + "';"
    })      
    .setResourceRoot(process.env.APP_DIR)
    .sourceMaps();
```

this part generates an error

```
, {
            data: "$fa-font-path:'" + fa_font_path + "';"
  }
```

Error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
```

**Note: this is not a duplication question, I already googled and read other answers.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### laravel 8 update

`data` property changed to `prependData`

On laravel 8 to pass data on your sass files you will need to add that string of sass code on an object like that one:

```
{
prependData: "$fa-font-path:'" + fa_font_path + "';"
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");


var fa_font_path =
    process.env.APP_DIR + "fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";


mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css", {
        prependData: "$fa-font-path:'" + fa_font_path + "';"
    })
    .setResourceRoot(process.env.APP_DIR)
    .sourceMaps()
    .version();
```